# Shorten string with a "..." body

Tags: php, string

Just like the the iPhone's app names that run to long, the name gets shortened. I really like  this method of shorting a name or a string rather then appending a "..." clause to it. Sorry if I am being confusing, I'm having trouble explaining what I am trying to do. So I'll show an example!

This is what I have, to append "..." to a shortened string (In PHP)

```
<?php
  $string = "This is a test script";

  if (strlen($string) >= 14)
    echo(substr($string), 0, 13). "..."); // This is a test...
  else
    echo($string); // This is a test script
?>
```

I would like to split up the name or string and keep the first say 10 characters, then insert "..." in the middle and lastly take the ending 5 letters of the string and display them. I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
<?php
  $string = "This is a test script";

  if (strlen($string) >= 20)
    echo(substr($string, 0, 10). "..." .substr($string, 15, 20)); //This is a ...script
  else
    echo($string);
?>
```

But realize that will not work in the regards that there are more then just 5 letters in the end. Any pointers into the write direction would be great, Thanks!

Comment: For clarification, is it a matter of not wanting to cut off a word in the middle or just being able to get the last 5 characters of the string?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
if (strlen($string) >= 20) {
    echo substr($string, 0, 10). " ... " . substr($string, -5);
}
else {
    echo $string;
}
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The third argument of [`substr()`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) is a length, not an end. Just pass `5` instead.

Also, `substr($string, -5)`.

Comment: This always gets me. Wish there was another substr function in php where it would take two positions as arguments instead of position and length.

Answer (score 1):

More generalized solution

```
function str_short($string, $length, $lastLength = 0, $symbol = '...')
{
    if (strlen($string) > $length) {
        $result = substr($string, 0, $length - $lastLength - strlen($symbol)) . $symbol;
        return $result . ($lastLength ? substr($string, - $lastLength) : '');
    }

    return $string;
}
```

usage

```
str_short(string, 20, 5, ' ... ')}}
```