# substr PHP shorten lengh of a string (WordPress Plugin)

Tags: php, string, wordpress, substr

I am a novice at PHP I am just learning. But I have come across a problem that I am having real trouble with.

I am working inside WordPress with a plug-in and I am trying to shorten a string within that plug-in so it just displays a small amount of text instead of a large section.

I know from reading this website and other including PHP.net that I need to use 'substr' The main problem is I think I need to add more than the string.

In my working one that does not shorten there is something with the string in ['post_content'] I am not sure how that works with the syntax of PHP.

This is what I have come up with using the resources I found. Also adding ... to the end would be great.

```
<?php

if (strlen($property) > 15) // if you want...
{
    $maxLength = 14;
    $property = substr($property, 0, $maxLength);
}
?>
```

And this is the working but without shortening

```
<?php echo $property['post_content']; ?>
```

Resources

[Get first n characters of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161816/get-first-n-characters-of-a-string)

[Shorten a text string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278756/shorten-a-text-string-in-php)

[Shorten string with a "..." body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122042/shorten-string-with-a-body)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: To me it is not clear what you are asking. Maybe you can make your question clearer. However, you may want to have a look at mb_substr() as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$property = $property['post_content'];
if (strlen($property) > 15) // if you want...
{
    $maxLength = 14;
    $property = substr($property, 0, $maxLength);
}
echo $property;
?>
```

Comment: What if he still wants to use `$property['post_content']` or other items of the `$property` array ?

Comment: On very 1st line he can declare another variable $postContent = $property['post_content'] and use it :)

Comment: or store whole array in another variable in start if he need it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (strlen($property['post_content']) > 15) // if you want...
{
   $mystring= substr($property['post_content'], 0,14);
}
echo $mystring; 
?>
```

Comment: user1374650 and Kamran Adil thank you for your replies i missed the echo how silly of me... Also if its not to much trouble how would i add it so it does not split the text mid sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$property = (strlen($property) > 15) ? substr($property,0,14): $property ;
```